# C# .NET 4.5 async ping responses are dropped

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, networking, .net-core

I've got a windows forms app that can scan a class C subnet (x.y.z.1-255) and display online devices, using the builtin `Ping` class.  I'm starting all 255 pings as async tasks.

While running with the debugger, I get all the responses I expect (about 30 devices) however if I run the exe outside the debugger (either Debug or Release build configuration) the app only processes responses for usually 3 or 4 devices, the rest time out.

Running Wireshark I can see both the ICMP requests *and* responses I expect.  So the responses appear to be getting dropped by the application.

Is there some I/O / task queueing that's going on which is causing responses to be dropped?  I've tried adjusting `System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100,200)` but it doesn't seem to have much, if any effect.

I've also tried running the tasks as `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));`  This seems to help but makes it take much longer than when running under the debugger.  So the debugger seems to be changing async behavior in the runtime.  Simplified code:

```
private async Task RangeScan(IPAddress subnet)
{

    byte[] subnetBytes = subnet.GetAddressBytes();

    List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();

    for (byte i = 1; i < 255; i++)
    {
        allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await PingDevice(new IPAddress(new byte[] { subnetBytes[0], subnetBytes[1], subnetBytes[2], (byte)i }))));
        // allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(
        //   async () => await PingDevice(new IPAddress(new byte[] { startBytes[0], startBytes[1], startBytes[2], cur })), 
        //   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

private async Task PingDevice(IPAddress curIp)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    try
    {
        //PingReply pr = ping.Send(curIp, 3000);
        PingReply pr = await ping.SendPingAsync(curIp, 3000);

        if (pr.Status != IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping failed to {0}: {1}", curIp, pr.Status);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("PingDevice response from {0}", curIp);
        
        // do more async work here (HTTP request to devices which responded...)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PingDevice err: {0}", e);
    }
```

So with a timeout of 3s, as expected it completes in under 4 seconds and when running under the debugger I receive and handle all responses.  If I use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` it takes 20 seconds or more, presumably because I'm starving a limited threadpool.  Apologies in advance if I'm doing something dumb, I'm more proficient in other languages/ Linux but I'm a bit green in the Windows/ .NET world.  Thanks!

Comment: Check the date of the exe in the debug and release folder and make sure you compiled both the debug and release versions.

Comment: What is `private async RangeScan(IPAddress subnet)`? Does it have a return type or you have just *obscured* it for some reason? Is it `void`? What calls `RangeScan()`? How?

Comment: Btw, you don't need `async ()=> await` there, just `allTasks.Add(PingDevice(new IPAddress(new byte[] { subnetBytes[0], subnetBytes[1], subnetBytes[2], i })));`

Comment: Return type fixed. Assume `RangeScan` is called from a button click handler, or a `main()`.  Not sure if it makes a difference, I've tried to boil the problem down to the essentials.

Comment: Right, but boiling it down too much doesn't serve you well, sometimes. For example, when you Release and deploy, all those `Console.WriteLine()` are totally useless. So, how do you actually use the results of those Tasks? Where do you *show* or store or log them? I don't see you returning anything. Try to provide an example that can give an idea of the full process. The actual one. Yes, what you do when the Tasks return their results is important. How you call `RangeScan()` needs to be part of the question.